# R setting library path via R_LIBS

Tags: r

I have read the R FAQS and other posts but I am a bit confused and would be grateful to know whether I did everything correctly.

In Windows, in order to modify the default library folder I created a file `Renviron.site` and put inside `E:/Programs/R-3.3.0/etc`.
The file has only one line saying

```
R_LIBS=E:/Rlibrary
```

When I open R and run `.libPaths()` I see `E:/Rlibrary` as [1] and the default R library  `E:/Programs/R-3.3.0/library` as [2].

This should mean that from now on all packages I will install will go in `E:/Rlibrary` but at the same time I will be able to load and use both packages in this folder and those in the default location. Am I correct?

Comment: This is correct, and also very easy to verify. `install.package` has a `lib` parameter which you can use to specify which folder to install to.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression there are many different possibilities and wanted to make sure the one I implemented is fine and does not cause any trouble when using libraries installed in different folders and so on.

Comment: @warmoverflow       If I may ask for further clarification: In a Windows PC where R-3.2.1 was already installed, in the list of R versions to use Rstudio shows both [64-bit] E:\Programs\R-3.2.1 and  [64-bit] E:\Programs\R-32~1.1. Also, the last item in the list returned by searchpaths() is "E:/Programs/R-32~1.1/library/base" . I am confused, why are the two path notations mixed?

Answer (score 3):

When you load a package via `library`, it will go through each directory in `.libPaths()` in turn to find the required package. If the package hasn't been found, you will get an error. This means you can have multiple versions of a package (in different directories), but the package that will be used is determined by the order of `.libPaths()`.

Regarding how `.libPaths()` is constructed, from `?.R_LIBS`

> The library search path is initialized at startup from the
>   environment variable 'R_LIBS' (which should be a colon-separated
>   list of directories at which R library trees are rooted) followed
>   by those in environment variable 'R_LIBS_USER'.  Only directories
>   which exist at the time will be included.