# Is there a reason not to use R_HOME/library as user library?

Tags: r

Usually, `install.packages()` installs CRAN packages under R_LIBS_USER. On a windows machine, this is usually a location in C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/r_version/.

However, I encountered the situation where all the CRAN packages are installed in the R_HOME/library folder (in my case: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2\library).
I wonder whether there are objective reasons that would suggest not to chose this folder for installing additional packages?

I consulted the [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Add_002don-packages) manual, but there is no advice on this topic.

Edit: The scenario is a single user machine.

Comment: thats because different users on one machine mighty use different versions of R and packages , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354538/r-setting-library-path-via-r-libs

Comment: I avoid `win-library` and always set `R_LIBS_USER` to something else. `win-library` is a name too OS dependent (it can exist in other OS's but that's not the point). Generally, I have a folder `R/R-<major version number>/site-library`. This makes it easier to `update.packages` whenever I update R.